# pyspark: Remove substring that is the value of another column and includes regex characters from the value of a given column

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

Let's say I have a Dataframe like

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
  [
    ('Test1 This is a test Test2','This is a test'),
    ('That is','That')
  ],
  ['text','name'])


+--------------------------+--------------+
|text                      |name          |
+--------------------------+--------------+
|Test1 This is a test Test2|This is a test|
|That is                   |That          |
+--------------------------+--------------+
```

If I apply `df.withColumn("new",F.expr("regexp_replace(text,name,'')")).show(truncate=False)` it works fine and results in

```
+--------------------------+--------------+------------+
|text                      |name          |new         |
+--------------------------+--------------+------------+
|Test1 This is a test Test2|This is a test|Test1  Test2|
|That is                   |That          | is         |
+--------------------------+--------------+------------+
```

So let's say I have the following Dataframe

```
+-----------------------------+-----------------+
|text                         |name             |
+-----------------------------+-----------------+
|Test1 This is a test(+1 Test2|This is a test(+1|
|That is                      |That             |
+-----------------------------+-----------------+
```

If I apply the the command from above I get the following error message:

> java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character
> '+&#39

What can I do so that this exception does not occur in the most "pyspark" way and keeping the value in text as is?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `regexp_replace` use ***`replace`*** function in spark.

> replace(str, search[, replace]) - Replaces all occurrences of search
> with replace.

**`Example:`**

```
df.show(10,False)
#+-----------------------------+-----------------+
#|text                         |name             |
#+-----------------------------+-----------------+
#|Test1 This is a test(+1 Test2|This is a test(+1|
#|That is                      |That             |
#+-----------------------------+-----------------+

df.withColumn("new",expr("replace(text,name,'')")).show(10,False)
#+-----------------------------+-----------------+------------+
#|text                         |name             |new         |
#+-----------------------------+-----------------+------------+
#|Test1 This is a test(+1 Test2|This is a test(+1|Test1  Test2|
#|That is                      |That             | is         |
#+-----------------------------+-----------------+------------+
```